# Как правильно удалить дубли одной страницы?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

Есть Главный файл сайта index.php. В вебмастере отображается такое:
[image]

Всё это соответственно одна страница index.php.

В поисковой выдаче, по некоторым запросам стоит страница /?ref=vc.ru хотя должна быть просто /

Как и где правильно настроить файлы, чтобы **удалить подобные дубли** и **оставить один адрес** доступа к главной страницы как /

Спасибо.

Comment: Используйте canonical name - в выдаче перестанут появляться дублирующие ссылки. Явно блокировать нужно в robots.txt записями вида Disallow: *ref=

Comment: @void правильно я понимаю, что тогда эти страницы вылетят из индекса? У меня много страниц и по хороошим запросам зашло с ссылками типа /?ref=vc.ru если я такое правильно напишу в robots.txt оно выпадет из поиска, не поменяется же просто на / ?

А если использовать Clean-param: ref ?

Comment: У site.com/page и site.com/page?ref=vc.ru должен быть canonical name site.com/page. Тогда не будет мешанины.